# PHP API call works on localhost, Postman but not live website

Tags: php, localhost

I am fairly beginner level in PHP and have an API from which I want to read out data. On my localhost it works fine and all outputs are as expected. Same goes for Postman app. It even works when I address the web API from my localhost instead of my local API. BUT as soon as I try to get a result ON my live website it returns NULL.

Note: Its a WordPress site. Localhost is done via Xampp. Online hosting via SiteGround. I had this working in the past but I don't know what happened (maybe I changed code slightly or something else) that is suddenly stopped working. API is a WordPress license manager plugin with preconfigured API. Domain name/IP/ and customer secrets are not original here.

```
$url = "https://example.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses?consumer_key=ck_xxxx&consumer_secret=cs_yyy";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => True,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>array (
     'Accept: application/json'),
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($response) ?> <br><br> <?php ;
$json_response =json_encode($response);
print_r($json_response) ?> <br><br> <?php ;
$info_display = curl_getinfo($curl);
print_r ($info_display); ?> <br><br> <?php 
$array_response = json_decode($response);
print_r($array_response); ?> <br> <br><?php 
$err = curl_error($curl);
var_dump($err); ?> <br> <br><?php 
curl_close($curl);
```

On my localhost this code produces this response which is exactly what I need:

```
> {"success":true,"data":{"id":"1","orderId":null,"productId":"2037","licenseKey":"1232edwfsd2","expiresAt":null,"validFor":"14","source":"2","status":"3","timesActivated":"0","timesActivatedMax":"1","createdAt":"2020-02-06
> 20:35:56","createdBy":"1","updatedAt":"2020-02-08
> 12:34:20","updatedBy":"1"}}
> 
> "{\"success\":true,\"data\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"orderId\":null,\"productId\":\"2037\",\"licenseKey\":\"1232edwfsd2\",\"expiresAt\":null,\"validFor\":\"14\",\"source\":\"2\",\"status\":\"3\",\"timesActivated\":\"0\",\"timesActivatedMax\":\"1\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-02-06
> 20:35:56\",\"createdBy\":\"1\",\"updatedAt\":\"2020-02-08
> 12:34:20\",\"updatedBy\":\"1\"}}"
> 
> Array ( [url] =>
> https://example.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_yyy
> [content_type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200
> [header_size] => 657 [request_size] => 250 [filetime] => -1
> [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] =>
> 2.164129 [namelookup_time] => 0.000694 [connect_time] => 0.256472 [pretransfer_time] => 0.40321 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] =>
> 205 [speed_download] => 94 [speed_upload] => 0
> [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1
> [starttransfer_time] => 2.164067 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url]
> => [primary_ip] => *censored by author* [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => *censored by author* [local_port] => *censored by author* [http_version] => 3 [protocol] => 2 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme]
> => HTTPS [appconnect_time_us] => 403002 [connect_time_us] => 256472 [namelookup_time_us] => 694 [pretransfer_time_us] => 403210
> [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 2164067
> [total_time_us] => 2164129 )
> 
> stdClass Object ( [success] => 1 [data] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1
> [orderId] => [productId] => 2037 [licenseKey] => 1232edwfsd2
> [expiresAt] => [validFor] => 14 [source] => 2 [status] => 3
> [timesActivated] => 0 [timesActivatedMax] => 1 [createdAt] =>
> 2020-02-06 20:35:56 [createdBy] => 1 [updatedAt] => 2020-02-08
> 12:34:20 [updatedBy] => 1 ) )
> 
> string(0) ""
> 
> status: 3 times activated: 0 times activated max: 1 last update:
> 2020-02-08 12:34:20
```

The same code on my live website crashes. So I need to comment out
`//print_r($response) ?> <br><br> <?php ;`

then I am able to get this result:

```
> "<\/meta><\/head><\/html>"
> 
> Array ( [url] =>
> https://example.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_yyy
> [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 277
> [request_size] => 254 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
> [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.01762 [namelookup_time] =>
> 0.000747 [connect_time] => 0.000873 [pretransfer_time] => 0.016955 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 96 [speed_download] => 5647
> [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1
> [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0.017479
> [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => *censored by author*
> [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => *censored by author*
> [local_port] => *censored by author* [http_version] => 3 [protocol] => 2
> [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => HTTPS [appconnect_time_us] =>
> 16862 [connect_time_us] => 873 [namelookup_time_us] => 747
> [pretransfer_time_us] => 16955 [redirect_time_us] => 0
> [starttransfer_time_us] => 17479 [total_time_us] => 17620 )
> 
> 
> 
> string(0) ""
> 
> status: times activated: times activated max: last update:
```

From my Developer console Network tab in Google Chrome I can see this. All requests return status 200:

```
Request URL: https://example.com/check-in/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: *censored by author*
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cache-control: no-transform, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 20:01:50 GMT
expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
host-header: 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024
link: <https://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://example.com/?p=2463>; rel=shortlink
server: nginx
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-httpd: 1
x-proxy-cache: BYPASS
x-proxy-cache-info: D NC:200000 UP:1
:authority: example.com
:method: GET
:path: /check-in/
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,nl-NL;q=0.6,nl;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: *censored by author*
referer: https://example.com/
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
```

Edit: Adding following code to the beginning of my php-snippet which I added to WordPress via php-snipped plugin:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I get this returned on the frontend:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 32

Notice: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 32
status:

Notice: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 33

Notice: Trying to get property 'timesActivated' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 33
times activated:

Notice: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 34

Notice: Trying to get property 'timesActivatedMax' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 34
times activated max:

Notice: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 35

Notice: Trying to get property 'updatedAt' of non-object in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 35
last update:
```

Comment: If it doesn't work on the frontend, please share *that* code, and perhaps some information on what you're saying in the developer console + network tab. Also try to look into formatting the information you're sharing. You want the 'code' button, not the 'quote' button. And yes, don't intersperse your JSON with print_r, it breaks the output.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this! The code above is exactly what I currently put out on the front end.I also adjusted formatting above and added my network log. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: All the Notices are unrelated. Although you should check your response before trying to access properties in it etc.

Comment: The response just seems to be empty on my webhost. Right? Accessing the properties of the response works fine on my localhost thats why I am lost when it suddenly doesnt on the webhost.What else can I do to check the response?

Comment: I would check to see if the response is null and/or false 
and/or an empty string before encoding it as a JSON object. Also check the result of your JSON encode, as it may fail... In your instance. Even if the response wasn't usually empty, you can't always be sure it won't be. Always worth protecting/error handling everything when receiving from an API, even if you are in control of both ends

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting something written to the output buffer before the wordpress API can output.

</meta></head></html>

I would check your environment on localhost matches production. Eg plugins, and theme files, and wordpress core. Your theme file may be echoing something in your header.

Other suggestions are :

If postman is working on Production, then it's an issue with your cUrl settings

Is it an SSL issue - you have disabled verify SSL on your cUrl - assuming you don't have SSL on your localhost, however Siteground my block cUrl requests from SSL sites which are not using SSL themselves. Also do you need the encoding set as an empty string?

Comment: Thanks man sounds like we are on to something! Indeed my localhost doesnt have SSL. My website on Siteground does. And yes postman works with the production site. The encoding empty string in the curl setopt is actually not needed. Commenting it out doesnt change anything though. Now I will go and check your suggestions and get back to you if find the smoking gun. Appreciate it!

Comment: I use insomnia myself and not postman, but if it's using curl itself internally it may list it's settings for each call

Comment: Local and web enviorment match one to one since I use the web enviorment to to export the site as a file and import it to my local enviorment with all-in one wordpress plugin. I disabled SSL on my website and it doesnt help (site is in maintenance mode anyway).  I tried Insomnia and generated php curl code with it. Again it works on my localhost but nothing on web. Something weird that I realise is I dont get errored out on my web site. As soon as response should be echoed it instead sends me back to my landing page. Any idea what s up with that? Still looking for curl setting for SG in parall

Answer (score 1):

It is solved but I must admit that I dont know what finally solved it. But it was unrelated to Siteground issues. In the end tried a thousand things and I deleted the entire subpage where the php code should have been run. I created a new page and tried all over and bam it worked. Very strange but thank you for the tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the following lines in to first line of script. All error will be shown, after that, this lines should be deleted in production environment

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Hey appreciate the reply! Just followed your recommendation and posted the result in an edit at the end of my post. It looks like the errors are happening at the very end when I want display certain values from what should be my json response. But no error seems to relate to the actual curl that seems to be unable to create the object I get on my localhost. Please let me know if this helped and/or you need more info.

Comment: as you see,  data object is null so trigger this error

Comment: yes but why is the object null on my webhost and never when I adress the same API via localhost or Postman?

Comment: I need your script?

Comment: Both your localhost and postman are different environments to your webhost. Have you seen if there are any siteground specific cUrl settings you need. I don't use them anymore personally so can't remember what their server setups were